# Can't add data from php array to json database

Tags: php

I have got problem with array. When i add string to json_encode it save in db but $object give me `[{},{},{}]`Can you tell me guys what i am doing wrong?

```
$objects = array();
$objects[] = new Person(1, 'John', 'Smith','java');
$objects[] = new Person(2, 'Stacy', 'Smith','php');

$Db ='./DB.json';
$saveInBase = json_encode($objects);
file_put_contents($Db, $saveInBase);
$loadFromBase = file_get_contents($Db);
$loadFromBase = json_decode($loadFromBase, true);
```

Comment: Your $objects array is empty you put nothing on it. Can you add also Person class?

Comment: It is working as expected. You're constructing array of objects and what you get is a JSON array of objects.

Comment: var_dump($objects) ?

Comment: Does `Person` implement [`JsonSerializable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) ?

Comment: What do you expect from this?  You won't be getting person instances when decoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please implement JsonSerializable on `Person` class, you only will have to implement `jsonSerialize` method,  here you have an example:

```
<?php
class Person implements JsonSerializable
{
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $last_name;
    private $lang;

    public function __construct($id, $name, $last_name, $lang)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->last_name = $last_name;
        $this->lang = $lang;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}

$objects = array();
$objects[] = new Person(1, 'John', 'Smith','java');
$objects[] = new Person(2, 'Stacy', 'Smith','php');

$Db ='./DB.json';
$saveInBase = json_encode($objects);
file_put_contents($Db, $saveInBase);
$loadFromBase = file_get_contents($Db);
$loadFromBase = json_decode($loadFromBase, true);
```